# method chain audio property in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an existing function that succesfully loads information into a div. It looks like this.

```
<div id="load_warnings">

      <!-- this is where the warnings will populate from ajax request -->

</div>



<script type="text/javascript">

  var auto_refresh = setInterval(
  function ()
  {
  $('#load_warnings').load('https://www.gastromend.com/warnings.php').fadeIn("slow"); 
  }, 20000); 


</script>
```

**Problem:**

I want to enhance this function further by playing a sound notification as well when this information is loaded into the div. I am struggling to understand how I would method chain `jquery` .play method in this set up.

> I tried this earlier without success - No audio played.

```
<div id="load_warnings">

      <!-- this is where the warnings will populate from ajax request -->

</div>


    <script type="text/javascript">

      var audioUrl = 'https://wwww.gastromend.com/resources/uploads/condodge_warning.mp3'; // declaration of audio path

      var audio = new Audio(audioUrl); // instantiation of audio object

      var auto_refresh = setInterval(
      function ()
      {
      $('#load_warnings').load('https://www.gastromend.com/warnings.php').fadeIn("slow").audio.play(); 
      }, 20000); 

    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the `audio` element to play once the `load()` AJAX request has completed. To do that invoke the `play()` method in the callback parameter of `load()`:

```js
var audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
  var $el = $('#load_warnings').load('https://www.gastromend.com/warnings.php', function() {
    audio.play();
    $el.fadeIn('slow');
  });
}, 20000);
```

Comment: I appreciate the steering, I will try this code now

Comment: Glad to help. Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/p3yzcgrf/. Note that it uses `$.ajax()` instead of `load()` as jsFiddle needs a POST request, not GET, but the pattern is the same

Comment: Rory I need this to work with the existing fadeIn method, how is that factored in here?. Your code never reverenced  that mate. thank you

Comment: Apologies, I mistakenly removed that call. I added it back in for you

Comment: Good question and great answer

Comment: hmmm the audio now works but the fadeIn of the previous information fails, should the fadeIn be in the call back

Comment: Potentially, although the original answer copied the way you had the logic in the question. It depends on how your HTML/CSS is structured. I amended the answer to show you how to do it, if needed.